# Extending a case class with companion object in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

I have 2 case classes with respective companion objects in 2 different files. I need to extend one of these classes and have the other class in the same file. Is this possible in scala? Any pointers on how to go about it?

Following are the existing classes A & B in files A.scala and B.scala

```
object A {
  def apply(){}
}
case class A(a: Int, b: Int) {}

object B {
  def apply() {}
}
case class B(x: Int, y: Int) {}
```

I need a 3rd class C which extends A and also has class B in a 3rd file C.scala.

Answer (score 1):

1) You shouldn't inherit from a case class

2) It is possible to declare two classes with the same name if they full names (including the package names) are different. So file `C.scala` must belong to a different package.

Comment: I should have made it clear, I was going to delete B.scala file and move its contents to C.scala. So in which case I guess it can be in the same package?

Comment: Yes, you can   //symbols to reach the minimal comment length